# Download v.redd.it videos as mp4

Tags: python-3.x, wget, reddit

I'm trying to make a Python script that allows the user to input a URL from a reddit post (v.redd.it) and download it as an mp4 to my Downloads folder.

This happens by the json of the URL being decoded and read, stored as a variable. Then the dictionary of the json is navigated to *fallback_url* where *wget.download* downloads the only video on the navigated url to my Downloads folder.

```
url = ''.join((url,'.json')) #add .json to end of url input for python to extract video url

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url: #python open url as http request
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) #read the json url
            file = data[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['secure_media']['reddit_video']['fallback_url'] #navigate the json to the url that has the mp4 (fallback_url)

            #debug
            print(file) #print if url is read
            time.sleep(4) #reddit has a request limit per minute (see below)
            wget.download(file,'C:/Users/x/Downloads/') #use wget to download the file, hopefully in .mp4, but doesn't work
```

> Make no more than thirty requests per minute. This allows some burstiness to your requests, but keep it sane. On average, we should see no more than one request every two seconds from you.

So first, I input the [Reddit URL](https://www.reddit.com/r/oddlysatisfying/comments/8ul77h/my_pasta_last_night/) and it is stored in variable **url**.
Then **.json** is added to the end *www.reddit.com/r/example/.../**.json*** by which the script will open the URL, storing the data of the Json into a dictionary, *data* variable. Then it will go through the tree of the dictionary, and getting to the key of *fallback_url* where the mp4 resides.

However, if you'd open that [url](https://v.redd.it/oe9jh00eur611/DASH_9_6_M), you can see it has only one element, the mp4 video. But when I use *wget.download(file, 'location')*, it downloads with the title as **DASH_9_6_M** (the title of the url) without an extension, which I'd hoped to be mp4. The file is extensionless, but has the same size as if it were an mp4.

So my question is, how do I get wget to download the video as an mp4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib.urlretrieve` to do it. Try `urllib.urlretrieve(file, "download.mp4")` for example.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

Answer (score 0):

Try `urllib.request.urlretrieve(file, "download.mp4")`

Comment: How would go about having the sound too?